# SAP DBTech JDBC: [257] (at 14): sql syntax error: missing column definition

Tags: hana

I want to create table in SAP HANA and my query is as follow:

```
create column table test12 (ID INTEGER, NAME VARCHAR(10), PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

and I encounter the problem

```
sql syntax error: missing column definition: line 1 col 21 (at pos 21)
```

I am new to HANA and I dont know how to get column definition, so please guide me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The command does **not** lead to an error on a standard HANA Express Edition. `Pos 21` points to the beginning of the table name. Is the provided command as-is in fact leading to the problem or is the actual command maybe different in some way?

Comment: I actually was able to solve the issue by creating the table using the schema and table name rather than only table name. For example, create row table "myschema"."table name" (ID Integer);

Comment: That's good that you managed to create a table. Note, however, that this has nothing to do with whether or not you create a `ROW` or `COLUMN` table. Both options work fine. The syntax shown in the question is **not** faulty and does work.